# Custom event shows in GA4 realtime when sending MP request from event builder, but not when same request is sent from postman

Tags: google-analytics, postman, httprequest, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I'm new to postman and experimenting with sending custom events to my GA4 property via measurement protocol requests. I want to use this for server-side implementations and offline events. Google's official documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) and their event builder is [here](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/). I've confirmed the event successfully populates in GA4 realtime report.

I'm using the `Post` method with the URL
`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${{measurement_id}}&api_secret=${{api_secret}}` and have also tried adding `/debug` to the start of the path. When I do, there are no error messages in the response body.

I've double-checked that I have the correct secret and am using the measurement id, not the data stream. I copy-pasted the body from the event builder. The body of my request is:

```json
{
    "client_id": "1192607906.1689072640",
    "events": [{
        {
            "name": "event_test_emma",
            "params": {}
        }
    }]
}
```

I've tried this as both json and text with the `Content-Type` request header updated to match.

Regarding headers, I've tried both the [default headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HutrD.png) and [editing/adding headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqNB4.png) so they match the [request headers from the event builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfe8b.png) as closely as possible.

No matter what I try, though, the event doesn't show in the realtime report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON have a double {{ for the "events".
Your JSON

```
{
    "client_id": "1192607906.1689072640",
    "events": [{
        {
            "name": "event_test_emma",
            "params": {}
        }
    }]
}
```

The problem

```
{
    "client_id": "1192607906.1689072640",
    "events":
```

> [{
> {

```
            "name": "event_test_emma",
            "params": {}
```

> }
> }]

```
}
```

Fixed JSON

```
{
    "client_id": "1192607906.1689072640",
    "events": 
        {
            "name": "event_test_emma",
            "params": {}
        }
    
}
```

And your postman should be like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried swapping out the variables in the URL for hard-coded values and changed the body of the request as you suggested. Still no dice.

Comment: Just to be sure, in post man in the URL your replace your ${{measurement_id}} by the right value? Same thing for the secret?

Comment: Yes! They're copy-pasted and not accidentally swapped.

Comment: I edit my answer, i do a mysake in the JSON. Try the json in my answer.